# Fix Three JS rendering distortion?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I have a very simple project, the user controls a camera with WASD and mouse. As the user moves around the scene, blocks are rendered. here's the block rendering code:

```js
function addBlock(pos){
    const geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80,80,80)
    const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)})
    const block =  new THREE.Mesh(geom,mat)

    block.position.x = pos.x * 80 + 40
    block.position.y = pos.y * 80 + 40
    block.position.z = pos.z * 80 + 40

    scene.add(block)
}
```

This issue arises when the user brings the camera far away from the blocks. Heres a picture of the bug:

[image]

As you can see, many of the blocks are distorted, and this gets worse as the camera gets further away. I tried setting the depthFunc of the block material to "lessThan" opposed to "LessEqualDepth", but that didn't change anything. I also tried giving the blocks different render orders, again this changed nothing. Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?